# Show titles using loop foreach inside banner

Tags: php, foreach

I have a banner and I'm using a loop foreach to show photos and their titles. Photos are displayed correctly but the titles are in another div below.
How can I display those title inside the loop ?

```
    <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <?php foreach($banners as $banner){?>
        <img src="../admin/<?php echo $banner->link; ?>" alt=""  />

        <?php } ?> // end of loop
    </div>

    <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">

    <?php echo $banner->title; ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

If I put `<?php } ?>` at the end of html code , the design of banner becomes confused

Comment: you should write "<?php echo $banner->title; ?>" with its DIV inside that above loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
     <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <?php foreach($banners as $banner){?>
          <img src="../admin/<?php echo $banner->link; ?>" alt=""  />

          <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
             <?php echo $banner->title; ?>
          </div>
        <?php } ?> // end of loop
     </div>
<div>
```

Comment: I think 2nd solution will not work because without its class[title class] it will create issue in design/layout.

Comment: yes, I tried that , the problem is that titles should be inside `<div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">...</div>`

Comment: @bjouma - exactly I am telling to Artista. Hope that first solution will work for you.

Comment: Thank you, I'll verify the layout